# Roblox PointsService:AwardPoints() local testing

Tags: roblox

Locally, in single play mode, any `PointsService:AwardPoints()` just fails silently. Even wrapping it inside `pcall()` does not give me anything, success nor error. Lines after that one are just not executed and function returns.

I'm guessing it will not work locally? But behavior is weird and I don't know how to develop/test it. I've been banging my head with this for hours, maybe too long and I'm missing something obvious?

EDIT: after more testing, to avoid adding more comments, I realized expected error is returned (`Processing PointsService:AwardPoints error: HTTP 0 (HTTP 403 (HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden))`) but only after I restart Studio and during first local run (Play). As soon as I hit Stop and then Play again, errors are no more returned and behavior is back to described.
Also, it appears to work in Test mode. I'm guessing that "Cleanup" button helps, while "Stop" in single play mode doesn't.
Still, quick testing with Single Play mode is not possible and it slows down development a lot

Answer (score 0):

This could be happening for two reasons:

1. You're trying to award PlayerPoints while in Play Solo, which is restricted.

- OR -

2. You're trying to award points from a LocalScript, which is also restricted. Points can only be awarded from the ServerSide to prevent exploiters from ruining the leaderboards.